How did Dom know a missile was coming so he could escape from Aimes?
In Fast X (2023), Dom was arrested by Aimes at an abandoned police station and transported in a convoy
across a bridge. Despite Dom's warning, Aimes did not buckle up. When a missile struck
the convoy, Dom, who had buckled himself in, escaped safely.
Since Dom was arrested, there was no way he could communicate with his team. So how
did he know that a missile was coming to hit the convoy so he could escape from Aimes?
How did Dom know a missile was coming so he could escape from Aimes?

If you listen carefully, the missile is making a high-pitched whistle as it travels. This is audible to us just after Dom starts staring at the ceiling, and presumably audible to him shortly before that.



